# Should a delegate be declared inside the class that will raise the event, or outside?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I have seen various examples of event handling. Here is one: [Event Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Sometimes I see the delegate declared outside the class that will raise the event (as in the link above), and sometimes inside (where *I* think it should be declared).

It makes more sense to me to declare the event *inside* the class that will raise the event. The reason being that the event that the class will declare is really just some sugar coating for helper methods etc. that are really doing the adding to, subtracting from, and invoking of the delegate etc.

Are there any best practices? Are there times when you would want to declare the delegate outside, and other times where you would want to declare the delegate inside? If so, how should it be decided which to do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically, these days you'd create your own class derived from `EventArgs`, and then just use [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) - there's no need to create a separate delegate type. So instead of `AlarmEventHandler`, you'd use `EventHandler<AlarmEventArgs>`. The `EventArgs`-derived class should generally be top-level (i.e. non-nested).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm trying to get a really good understanding of delegates and how to use them intelligently, which is why I'm still harping on non-generic delegates (plus I'm preparing for 70-536).

Comment: @Richard: In terms of *understanding* delegates, it's pretty much irrelevant whether they're declared as top-level types or not. It's also worth making sure you have a firm grasp on the difference between events and delegates. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I have spent about a week now mostly on delegates, events, and how they are used and what they are (including the CIL that is generated when you declare them, etc.). I bought your book a few weeks ago, but I hadn't looked through it thoruoghly yet, and so wasn't aware you have a section on delegates and events. These have been so confusing because of the all the interpreted things the compiler is doing as a result of the very terse declarations that C# encourages when using them. I will read this article and the section in your book now!

Comment: Why shouldn't it be nested?

Comment: @shinzou: Generally, in my view, it's worth avoiding declaring public nested types unless they're very tightly coupled with the containing class. (That's also part of the MS design guidelines somewhere...)

Answer (score 6):

I would declare them outside as they are ment to be used by other classes as well - the consumers of the event. I would keep the delegate in the same file as the class if the delegate is specific to this class.

It's less of the problem if you use generic version of `EventHandler<TEventAgrs>`, available in .NET 2.0 and newer, as you need to declare your custom `EventArgs` only.

Comment: Are you referring to when you add a method to the delegate, like `clock.Alarm += new AlarmEventHandler(w.AlarmRang);` where `AlarmEventHandler` is the instance of the delegate?

Comment: Yes, the class that exposes the event and the class that consumes the event need to know the delegate type. In newer versions of .NET you can use lambdas and anonymous delegates, which makes this requirement obsolete

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, there are few examples of public accessible nested "objects" in the CLR (classes/structs/delegates/enums). So delegates normally are "external" to the class.

BUT from the .NET 3.5 onward there has been the idea of using "generic" delegates (`Func<T>`, `Action<T>`, `Predicate<T>`) instead of an ever-increasing number of incompatible delegates

Comment: There are definitely some: `List<T>.Enumerator` springs to mind.